# change height of custom Dynamically problem iphone

Tags: ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0, uitableview

```
Hi every one i have use two custom cell in a table view at a time .

Cell one contains labels and buttons 

Cell Two Contain next and previous Button 

i am adding cell Two at last index of the table view my question is that how can i change the height of cell 2 dynamically

Height of Cell one is 110 and i want the height of cell two is 80 what can i do any idea??
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out `heightForRowAtIndexPath` [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

and return 110 or 80 depending on the indexPath.row

Answer (score 0):

```
// considered your table have single section and multiple rows...  

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    if(indexPath.row == [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0]-1){
            return 80;
        }
        return 110;

    }
```